# how to work function bindNode() for habtm relation

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-acl

M using cake 2.6.0 
My model user.php 
In user model it giving

error : Undefined index: group_id [APP\Model\User.php]

```
    public function bindNode($user) {

        return array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => $user['User']['group_id']);
    }

 public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Group' => array(
            'className' => 'Group',
            'joinTable' => 'groups_users',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'group_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
        )
    );
```

login.ctp

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
    'url' => array(
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action' => 'login'
    )
));
echo $this->Form->input('User.username');
echo $this->Form->input('User.password');
echo $this->Form->input('User.group_id', array('type' => 'select', 'empty' => '---Select Role---'));

echo $this->Form->end('Login');
```

I want to get user.group_id in bindNode() function, which select while login time.

Comment: put  `debug($user)` before return array. you would see user  `group_id` is there or not.

Comment: No group_id is not there. array(
 'User' => array(
  'id' => '1',
  'name' => 'Dhruvi bhavsar',
  'username' => 'dhruvi',
  'active' => '1',
  'email' => 'dhruvi@gmail.com'
 )
)